# Prevent clusters refresh when modifying the style of a feature in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, performance, clustering

I am increasing the size of a feature on mouse hover, but there is a significant delay because, as I've noticed in a browser Performance analysis, all the clusters are refreshed and re-rendered when the feature's "changed" event is trigger.
I've tried scaling the feature in two ways:

```
marker.getStyle()[0].getImage().setScale(1 * growthRate);
marker.getStyle()[1].getImage().setScale(1.5 * growthRate);
marker.changed()
```

and

```
var bg = marker.getStyle()[0];
var icon = marker.getStyle()[1];
bg.getImage().setScale(1 * growthRate);
icon.getImage().setScale(1.5 * growthRate);
marker.setStyle([bg, icon]);
```

This is how I initialize my layers and the map:

```
      this.markerVectors = new ol.source.Vector({features: []});

      var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
        distance: 50,
        source: this.markerVectors
      });
      
      var clusterCache = {};
      var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: clusterSource,
        style: function (feature) {
          var size = feature.get('features').length;
          if (size === 1){
            return feature.get('features')[0].getStyle();
          }
          var color = '3399CC';
          
          feature.setProperties({ftype: 'cluster');
          var textColor = '#' + utils.invertHex(color);
          color = '#' + color;
          if (clusterCache[size] !== undefined){
            return clusterCache[size];
          }
          var radius = 20;
          if (size < 10) radius = 12;
          if (size >= 10) radius = 15;
          if (size >= 100) radius = 20;
          if (size >= 1000) radius = 30;
          style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
              radius: radius,
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#000000',
                width: 2
              }),
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: color,
              }),
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
              text: size.toString(),
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: textColor//'#fff',
              }),
              scale: [1.2,1.2]
            }),
            zIndex: 8
          });
          clusterCache[size] = style;
          return style;
        },
      });


      this.mapObj = new ol.Map({
        view: new ol.View({
          center: this.center,
          zoom: 8
        }),
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
          clusters
        ],
        target: 'map'
      });
```

On smaller input (<100 features) the delay is not noticeable, but on usual input of >1000 features the delay is about 200-500ms. Is there a way to update a feature without triggering the clusters' update function? Or at least to trigger only the cluster in which the feature is present (although it won't modify the state/style of the cluster).

Comment: Please edit your question and add more of relevant code regarding cluster layer creation.

Comment: @TomazicM I've added a few more things, hopefully it will clear things up a little.

Comment: You are talking about features, but is seems you want to change size of cluster markers. Do you want to change it's size only in the case of single (nonclustered) marker or also in the case of clustered marker?

Comment: @TomazicM Only for the non-clustered markers, although I might implement it for cluster markers as well. It is just a hover effect, it doesn't change the features' properties and that's why I consider that it shouldn't trigger cluster updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one possible solution where you avoid fighting with the consequences of `change` event.

You can create an extra layer to which you clone marker when mouse is over it and can style it there to you desire, without affecting cluster layer. When mouse goes out, you just clear that layer.

Relevant code could then look something like this (base code taken from official OL cluster example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html):

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: parseInt(distance.value, 10),
  source: source
});

var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource,
  style: clusterStyle
});

var selectedFeatureSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var selectedFeature = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: selectedFeatureSource,
  style: selectedStyle
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM(),
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [raster, clusters, selectedFeature],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

var selectedOrigFeature = null;
var selectedFeature = null;

map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature, layer) {
      return feature;
  });
  if (feature != selectedOrigFeature) {
    if (selectedFeature) {
      selectedFeatureSource.clear();
      selectedOrigFeature = null;
      selectedFeature = null;
    }
  }
  if (feature) {
    if (feature.get('features').length == 1) {
      selectedOrigFeature = feature;
      selectedFeature = selectedOrigFeature.clone();
      selectedFeatureSource.addFeature(selectedFeature);
    }
  }
});
```

This is for the case when you want change style just of nonclustered markers (as stated in your comment). If you want to change style for all markers, just leave condition `if (feature.get('features').length == 1)` out.

Comment: This indeed seems like the optimal solution. Thank you!